# Can't view vote counts without the mouse

Tags: bug, status-completed, accessibility

I can't <kbd>tab</kbd> to the space in between the vote buttons that shows the current score, that users with 1,000+ rep can click on to view up votes/downvotes.

The focus goes right from the sort tabs to the "share" button.

<sub>If you're confused as to why it's important that things be accessible without the mouse, please read up on [keyboard accessibility](https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/). While I thankfully don't have any physical problems with using 
a mouse, I'm using my time with a broken mouse to give accessibility feedback so that people who need it can get a better site experience.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for raising more awareness towards [WAI](https://www.w3.org/WAI/) where keyboard accessibility plays a major part <3 !

Comment: Considering adding "Mouse is required to use all site features" [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need). :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like this has been fixed; I can now <kbd>tab</kbd> to see the vote counts:

[image: image of vote count with keyboard focus on it]

This should probably be tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), then.